# Two continuous, strictly decreasing, concave functions can intersect at most once?

Tags: derivatives, monotone-functions

Suppose we have $f:R^{++} \rightarrow R$ and $g:R^{++} \rightarrow R$ s.t. both f and g are continuous functions. Further $f'(x)<0,g'(x)<0$ and $f''(x)>0,g''(x)>0$ for all x in their domains. Finally, f and g both tend towards infinity as x goes to 0 and both tend towards -infinity when x is large. My intuition is that f and g can cross at most once. However, I am having trouble ruling out the possibility that they cross twice. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `f′′(x)>0, g′′(x)>0` Did you then mean *convex* functions, maybe?

Comment: The end conditions (at 0 and large x) are puzzling to me I have trouble envisioning any function as you described.  A simpler case would go to 0 for large x.  In that case two functions could easily cross twice.

Comment: Yes they are convex, you could also think of them as always being concave up if that terminology is more helpful. 

I agree that x going to 0 is an easier case to consider. I already have found examples where this is true. In this particular case, my intuition tells me that the limiting behavior combined with the knowledge of the first and second derivative behavior is what gives the result. I have not quite been able to piece it together though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can totally happen.  You could start with such a function $f$ and then let $g$ be $f$ modified by very gentle oscillations, so gentle that they don't change the sign of the first or second derivative.

For instance, consider $f(x)=-\log x$ and $g(x)=-\log x+C\frac{\sin x}{1+x^3}$ for some constant $C>0$.  We have $f'(x)=-1/x<0$ and $f''(x)=1/x^2>0$ for all $x>0$.  The first and second derivative of $\frac{\sin x}{1+x^3}$ are nasty but it is easy to see that they are both bounded in absolute value by a constant multiple of $\frac{1}{1+x^3}$.  If we choose $C$ small enough, then, this will not be enough to change the sign of $f'(x)$ or $f''(x)$, so $g'(x)$ is still negative and $g''(x)$ is still positive.

So, $f$ and $g$ satisfy your conditions.  However, they cross infinitely many times, at every integer multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: I am having trouble visualizing your example and reconciling it with what the second derivative tells us in theory. If g''(x)>0 for all x, my intuition is that g(x) cannot possess oscillations. This would imply that the concavity of g(x) changes infinitely many times, which contradicts g''(x)>0 for all x, right? Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: The oscillations are so small that they do not change the concavity.  You may find it helpful to look at a graph of the function $x^2+\sin(x)$.  The $\sin(x)$ term introduces some small "wobbles" compared to the graph of $x^2$, but not enough to ever change its concavity (because the second derivative of $\sin(x)$ never gets below $-1$ while the second derivative of $x^2$ is always $2$).  See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+x%5E2%2Bsin(x)+and+x%5E2+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D8 for instance.

Comment: So in my example, $g(x)$ isn't literally oscillating in the sense of going back and forth between the same values.  It is only oscillating _relative_ to $f(x)$, since the difference $g(x)-f(x)$ is going back and forth around $0$.

Comment: Ah I understand. Thank you for the guidance, this definitely answers my question. For my particular case, the functions of interest will not have any oscillations (no periodicity). I am wondering if multiple intersections is possible with this additional restriction?

Comment: I don't think there is any rigorous way to describe what an "oscillation" is in this sense.  For instance, who's to say that $g(x)$ has oscillations and $f(x)$ does not?  From the perspective of $g(x)$, it's $f(x)$ that has the oscillations!